If $\mu$ extends $\mu_{0}$, then $\int f d\mu_0= \int f d\mu$
Let $(X, \mathcal{A}_{0}, \mu_{0})$ be a measure space and let $\mu: \mathcal{A} \rightarrow [0, \infty]$ be an extension measure of $\mu_{0}$ (where $\mathcal{A}_{0} \subseteq \mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{A}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra ). Given a function $f: X \rightarrow [0,\infty]$ $\mathcal{A}_{0}$- measurable, is it true that $f$ is also $\mathcal{A}$-measurable and $\int f d\mu_0= \int f d\mu$?
I'm actually interested in the specific case where $\mu := \mu_{0}^*|_{\mathcal{M}_{\mu_{0}^*}}$ is the restriction of $\mu_{ 0} ^*$ (the outer measure induced by $\mu_{0}$ ) to $\mathcal{M}_{\mu_{0}^*}$ (the $\sigma$-algebra of $\mu_{ 0} ^*$-measurable sets). So if the general result is not true, would it be true if $\mu := \mu_{0}^*|_{\mathcal{M}_{\mu_{0}^*}}$ ?
